# greatest product of consecutive digits in numbers python

Tags: python

My program has the purpose of determining the greatest product of a certain amount of consecutive digits. For example the program prompts the user for a string of numbers (ex 255969406) and for the size of consecutive digits (3), thus my program will determine what the greatest product of 3 consecutive digits in the number provided is, my program compiles and runs but the product returned is incorrect.

```
def Pro(dig,snum):
    number = 1
    pr = 0
    for x in xrange(0,dig-1):
        pr = int(snum[x])
        number = pr*number
    return number

def Product(dig,indx,snum):
    number = 1
    pr = 0
    for x in xrange(1,dig):

        pr = int(snum[indx+x])
        number = pr*number
    return number


def Main():     
    num = raw_input("Enter a string of digits")
    dig = input("Input number of digits in group")
    x = 1

    val = Pro(dig,num)
    grps = int(len(num)/ dig)
    while x<grps:
        val2= Product(dig,x,num)
        if val2>val:
                val = val2
        x +=1
    print("The max product of " + str(dig) +" consecutive digits in " + num + " is " + str(val))
if __name__ == "__main__":
Main()
```

Comment: note i gave group of 3 as an example the user chooses how large the group is ie if the number given is 4586948304 and the user chooses 4 the program should determine what 4 consecutive numbers has the greatest product

Answer (score 1):

You can try this out:

```
x = '134214257248'

m = 0

for i in range(len(x) - 2):
    m = max(m, int(x[i])*int(x[i+1])*int(x[i+2]))

print m

# 2*5*7 = 70
70
```

EDIT: Accept any amount (n) of consecutive digits

```
import numpy as np

x = '134214257248'

m = 0
n = 3

for i in range(len(x) - n + 1):
    m = max(m, np.prod(list(int(l) for l in x[i:i + n])))

print m

70
```

Comment: is there any way to modify this so you can use it with any amount of consecutive digts, such as 2 or 5 not just 3